# Jobs being removed from database without being processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Without the delayed_job gem and associated code changes, emails are processing correctly through my app.

Following the [common problems](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems) guide found on the github wiki for the gem under the heading 'jobs are silently removed from the database', I did the following:

**/config/initializers/delayed_job.rb**

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

After restarting the workers and the rails server, I tried again, but I can still see the delayed_job row being added when I set the email to process, and quickly deleted thereafter.

The email is being called from a controller as follows:

`PresentationMailer.delay.presentation_invitation(@presentation)`

From a rails console (expected, I've never had a successful job run yet):

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Delayed::Job.last
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` ORDER BY `delayed_jobs`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Excerpt from **/log/delayed_job.log**

```
2013-08-06T16:30:54+1200: [Worker(delayed_job host:192.168.1.251 pid:26688)] Job Class#presentation_invitation (id=9) RUNNING
2013-08-06T16:30:54+1200: [Worker(delayed_job host:192.168.1.251 pid:26688)] Job Class#presentation_invitation (id=9) COMPLETED after 0.0081
2013-08-06T16:30:54+1200: [Worker(delayed_job host:192.168.1.251 pid:26688)] 1 jobs processed at 9.1940 j/s, 0 failed
```

Which seems to suggest that no errors are being hit; yet no mail is being sent (confirmed with wireshark, no packets going to my SMTP server)

**/app/mailers/presentation_mailer.rb**

```
class PresentationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application
  default from: "alias@domain.test"
  def presentation_invitation(email)
    return false if email.sent
    contact = nil
    presentation = nil
    if email.emailable.class == PresentationAttendee
      contact = email.emailable.contact
      presentation = email.emailable.presentation
    else
      return false
    end
    ics = RiCal.Event do
      description "Presentation"
      dtstart DateTime.parse(presentation.date_time)
      dtend DateTime.parse((presentation.date_time + 30*60).to_s) # (90 minutes length)
      location presentation.presentation_location.to_s
      add_attendee contact.email_address
      alarm do
        description "Presentation"
      end
    end
    attachments["calendar-reminder.ics"] = {mime_type: "text/calendar", content: ics.export}
    @email = email
    @contact = contact
    @presentation = presentation
    content_type = "multipart/mixed" # Required for background processing of mail to complete with attachment in tact
    mail to: "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name} <#{contact.email_address}>", subject: email.email_content.subject if email.email_content
  end
end
```

Any ideas for how I can further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Post the delayed_job log file in the log folder. Check it.

Comment: delayed_job log excerpt posted.

Comment: Have you any delayed job initializer? If so post it. This is very weird. One more suggestion would be if you could create a non mail job and see if it works.

Comment: Could you post the mailer as well?

Comment: There is a one line initializer, as near the top of my post. Nothing aside from that related to delayed_job. Mailer posted.

Comment: I have same issue. My method is executing in console, but when i kept that in background job, delayed_job just added it and removed it. Not sure why it is doing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

create an initializer and add the line

`require 'ri_cal'`

Now try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: This still had the same problem. Instead of continuing down this route, I've gone with the sidekiq gem instead of delayed_job, which worked almost immediately after setting up. It's not quite what I wanted in that I preferred to have the jobs stored in the DB instead of redis, but for now I'll go with what works.